# The way to overwrite list.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, template, catalog, catalogsearch

A bit new to Magento but need to do next thing:

- Hierarchial catalog(HC) [Category > Subcategory('s) > Products]

I found on the web that i can rewrite  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`
to actually gain what I need. But turns out that `Magento_CatalogSearch` using same file from `Magento_Catalog` to show results.

Is there some switch or variable where i can spot when search is called?
Or some other way to reload how HC loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Override `vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml` to your theme inside `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout` and add below catalogsearch_result_index.xml in layout folder:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::product/search-list.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="search.search_terms_log" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::search_terms_log.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="search_terms_log" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchTermsLog</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
   ```
2. Copy and rename the file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/product/search-list.phtml`

We have not tested it but it will work.
OR
in list.phtml try with below code :

```
print_r($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName());
```

if you get return like : catalogsearch_result_index in the search page. then add a condition for search result as below:

```
if($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalogsearch_result_index '){
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: @saurebh-dwivedi, it's not working for me... any other solution?

Comment: I have updated in answer please check if it helps you.

Comment: @saurebh-dwivedi, Yes thats it... at least i can work with it.